# How to remove the URLs from the auto generated Sitemap file of Salesforce community?

Tags: community-cloud, seo

One of our community has certain articles that are NOT visible to public (IsVisibleInPkb = false) but these article URLs are included in Sitemap and are available for search engines for crawling. Since these are not visible to public crawlers are taking much time and resulting in high crawl budget. This prevents the search engine to continue crawling the entire website including the ULRs that are visible for public. This issue might cause the site to be ranked as low quality.

How to remove these article (IsVisibleInPkb = false) URLs from sitemap file?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only way to remove URL's from sitemap is to unassign the topic associated to articles. Sitemap is auto generated every weekend, but if you unassign the topic to the articles and generate the sitemap from your experience cloud builder settings that will remove the url from sitemap.

Please refer below article:
https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000384637&type=1

Thank you